# common table expression in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, c#-3.0, common-table-expression

if possible to directly call CTE in C sharp..Can any one tell me how to call CTE in C sharp??

Answer (score 5):

A CTE in SQL Server is part of a regular SQL query statement - so whatever you do to execute a SQL query will also work with a CTE:

```
string cteQuery = ";WITH yourCTE AS (SELECT .... FROM :... WHERE.....) SELECT * FROM yourCTE";

using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(cteQuery, _con))
{
   // provide parameters to the query, if needed

   _con.Open();

   using(SqlDataReader rdr = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       while(rdr.Read())
       {
          // grab your data from the data reader here
       }

       rdr.Close();
   }

   _con.Close();
}
```

Or what are you trying to do??

Comment: WITH Sales_CTE (NumberOfOrders,fee)
AS
(
    SELECT id,name
    FROM ex 
    
)
SELECT *
FROM Sales_CTE;
GO

This is my CTE... can i call directly Sales_CTE in C sharp.please tel me how to call

Comment: As marc (and myself) suggested, you can. It's the same as executing any other query from C#...

Answer (score 0):

A CTE is just part of a T-SQL query, so executing the statement from C# should call the CTE. I'm not sure if that answers your question?